# mssql - copy different datatypes datas from one column to another column in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Tried to copy data's from one column to another column in same table by using following code.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[name] SET [name_HId] = [name_Id]
```

while running this query its showing an error which is

```
Operand type clash: int is incompatible with hierarchyid
```

Here the name_HId is in `hierarchyid` datatype and the name_Id is in `int`.

how can solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried an explicit cast?

Comment: Why and How you need Update the column in `hierarchyid` with the column in `int` ? it is cannot be done, simply `int is incompatible with hierarchyid `

Comment: can you share table definition ie Describe tablename ;  in you case there is data type miss match.

Comment: @tafia can i use a loop to convert int into hierarchyid while coping those datas from one column to another column.

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader i hv a data column with int, now i need to copy all the datas to another column which is in hierarchyid datatype. i need those to columns. this is my situation.

Comment: @Coder, The datatypes within the both columns MUST be compatible, `int is incompatible with hierarchyid `.

Answer (score 0):

add the slashes and then cast to hierarchyid

```
select cast('/' +cast(5 as varchar)+ '/' as hierarchyid)
```

When you cast a hierarchyid to string, it will look something like '/5/' or '/5/8/'

Comment: Not sure why I got a down vote for that. I've tested the code I posted and it was working for me.

Answer (score 0):

just cast the int value to varchar:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[name] 
SET [name_HId] = Cast([name_Id] as varchar(max))
```